# Help! Is our contractor skimping on us on our basement foundation repair?

Tags: concrete, basement, foundation, construction, contractors

Our contractors just finished a job to completely redo one of our basement foundation wall, but we have some questions about the quality of the work.

They assured us it was fine, but is it normal to:

1. Have a gap like that between the foundation wall and the basement ceiling? To the point where I can see the light from outside (they stated it was because our house was not level and that the ventilation helps keep the inside dry…) - see photo 1
2. Have wet spots in the concrete just after one day of rain (albeit, pouring rain)… to the point where there’s a crack on the concrete under the window - see photos 2 and 3 (they argued photo three was just drying concrete)
3. Not add a Drylok coat over the concrete foundation wall? They told us it was because they used hydraulic stucco and it didn’t need Drylok.

For context, this was the scope of job done, in their words, (sic…. everywhere) “8x8x8 Cavedy block founding wall reinforced with red tech rebar replaced on inside basement/foundation outside of the foundation was dug down 6 feet and new poured sma hot and cold foundation concrete 1 feet Departure from New foundation wall 2 new triple glase windows was installed at no cost”

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That "ventilation helps to keep the inside dry" made me laugh. For a foundation to hold up a structure, it has to be touching the structure. Did they periodically put spacers or wedges in there to carry the loads from above? I don't know standard practice for residential stuff like this, but I expect they typically wedge the gap with 1-1/2" wide spacers every 16 inches and then caulk the rest. If you're obsessive about filling the gap with load carrying material, there's stuff called hydraulic cement that runs pretty nicely and expands a little as it cures. That would be the product to use.

Comment: After the "keeps it dry" BS, I'd be questioning everything else, too. I'm somewhat sympathetic to the contractor on the water around the window because of how high up on the wall the water stains go. At the top of the window that water stain looks well above grade where I wouldn't expect that to be one of the heaviest spots. Is there something going on outside the house at that spot that accumulates water for infiltration? Is blown rain coming through a gap analogous to that from your first photo?

Comment: That crack and water in the 3rd photo, is that above or below the "dug down 6 feet"? Did they apply the hydraulic stucco on the exterior also? Specifically, I'm curious if that crack is below any water mitigation that was performed on the outside of the wall. As you can imagine, these mitigation measures work better on the outside of the wall where compressive pressure holds them tight to the wall. Even if this is bleed water moving out of the concrete, there may be no redundant layer on the outside at that elevation.

Comment: That "was installed at no cost" suggests that your contractor thinks that it's you who's skimping.

Comment: In commercial construction, if I got a response like that "keep the inside dry," I would probably be pissed enough to bring in another contractor to pick apart the quality of the work, redo the demonstrably out of spec work, and subtract off the second guy's costs from the check I sent to the first guy. I'm cautious about offering such fire-breathing advice in your case because it sounds like there was some tit-for-tat retaliation happening here. If the caulking for that gap is out-of-scope but typically performed as a courtesy, then it could be a minor skirmish in the context of a larger war.

Comment: This was foundation work. Was a permit pulled? If so, get the inspector from your local building commission. This appears to be sub-par work, and the inspector will have the big stick required to get them to move. If they don't then you have grounds to withhold final payment until the work is done correctly.